# Adicionar notação de moeda em R

Tags: r

Estou com o seguinte problema aqui no trabalho: num data frame eu tenho uma coluna de Valor bruto em determinadas data:

```
2016-02-01   751434574
2016-03-01   748873781
2016-04-01   755528121
```

Para trabalhar no R sem problemas, mas preciso elaborar um relatório de gastos e meu chefe pediu para que aparecesse no formato de moeda, como abaixo:

```
2016-02-01   R$ 751.434.574
2016-03-01   R$ 748.873.781
2016-04-01   R$ 755.528.121
```

Há alguma função de algum pacote que já faça isso, ou vou ter criar uma expressão regular?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma solução simples e concisa usando o pacote `stringr`:

```
# Bibliotecas necessárias
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

# Formatação para Reais
format_real <- function(values, nsmall = 0) {
  values %>%
    as.numeric() %>%
    format(nsmall = nsmall, decimal.mark = ",", big.mark = ".") %>%
    str_trim() %>%
    str_c("R$ ", .)
}

# Entrada exemplo
tabela <- data.frame(
  data = c("2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01"),
  valor = c(751434574, 2435, 3454575678))

# Aplicação da formatação
format_real(tabela$valor)
#> [1] "R$ 751.434.574"   "R$ 2.435"         "R$ 3.454.575.678"
```

Caso você deseje adicionar casas depois da vírgula, simplesmente use o argumento `nsmall = 2`.

Comment: Era algo assim mesmo que eu estava procurando, em breve testo e respondo

Answer (score 2):

Pode não ser a forma mais elegante (ou com a ajuda de algum pacote), mas dá pra fazer no braço

Primeiro eu utilizei duas funções (`right` e `left`) nos moldes das funções `direita` e `esquerda` do Excel.

```
left <- function(string,char){
  substr(string, 1, char)
}
right <- function(string, char){
  substr(string, nchar(string)-(char-1), nchar(string))
}
```

Depois foi utilizar essas funções com o comando `paste`

```
dados <- data.frame(data = c("2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01"),
                    valor = c(751434574,748873781,755528121))
dados$valor2 <- paste(left(dados$valor, 6),
                      right(dados$valor, 3), sep = ".")
dados$valor2 <- paste(left(dados$valor2, 3), right(dados$valor2, 7),
                      sep = ".")
dados$valor2 <- paste("R$", dados$valor2, sep = " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando `paste` e `format`:

```
paste("R$", format(3454575678, decimal.mark = ",", big.mark = ".", nsmall = 2)) 
"R$ 3.454.575.678,00"
```